# Communication between C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, cross-platform, buffer, communication

I am looking for an efficient and smart way to send data between a C++-program and a Python-script. I have a C++ program which calculates some coordinates in-real-time 30Hz. And I wanna access these coordinates with a Python-script. My first idea was to simply create a .txt-file and write the coordinates to it, and then have Python open the file and read. But I figured that it must be a smarter and more efficient way using the RAM and not the harddrive.

Does anyone have any good solutions for this? The C++ program should write 3coordinates (x,y,z) to some sort of buffer or file, and the Python program can open it and read them. Ideally the C++-program overwrites the coordinates every time and there's no problem with reading and writing to the file/buffer at the same time.

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html

Comment: You're saying values will be calculated periodically, not just once right?  Have you looked into using sockets with a simple client/server set-up?

Comment: If you're on UNIX systems, you can use named pipes. Otherwise sockets is the way to go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two basic options:

- Run the C++ code and the python code as two separate programs, in two separate processes, and use a [IPC mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)
- Link the C++ code against your code, as grc suggested.

The first option is probably better if you already have a complete complex C++ program written. Also, it's generally easier to debug and maintain.

As for a specific IPC mechanism, sockets are commonly used because they have somewhat standardized cross-platform APIs at the OS level, and still work if you need the two programs running on different machines. Sockets should be more than enough for transferring three coordinates 30 times each second, if you're dealing with a modern desktop machine.

If you really need more performance, you could look into (named or named) pipes, but you'll probably need some extra work on the C++ side to make it cross-platform.

Comment: What's the difference between a socket where both ends are local and a named pipe?  The OS _should_ treat them basically the same.

Comment: @JamesKanze While I don't have a reference nor benchmark handy, I think they're very different. Even if you use a socket bound (listening) only on a local address (such as `127.0.0.1`), the OS will still need to go through all the network related processing: wrap the (application) payload into a transport (UDP/TCP) packet and wrap the transport packet into a IP packet (it probably doesn't need to go down to the link layer, though). Even if the packets never touch the physical interface, this is still a significant overhead compared to a pipe, which the OS treats simply as a opaque binary strm

Comment: @goncalopp You shouldn't have to.  I'll admit that I haven't looked at this in a long time, but at least under Sun OS (pre-Solaris), there was something called a Unix Domain Socket, which worked more or less like a pipe, except that it kept track of the record ends; if memory serves me correctly, it automatically converted a socket opened on the same machine to a Unix Domain Socket.  (Not very intelligently: IIRC, it only did so if the target was "localhost", not if you actually used the machine's name.)

Comment: @JamesKanze UNIX sockets still exist in Linux, OS X, and the various BSDs - but I had never heard about automatic conversion from Berkeley sockets (I never worked with Sun OS). They don't exist on Windows, so the behaviour would always be platform-dependent

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use Named Pipes for communication between a python and C++ program if the processes are on the same machine.

However for different machines sockets are the best option.