# Can I read a given variable of a windows application (c++) with python?

Tags: python, c++, variables

I have a c++ application. I need to read a variable of this. I have a source code as well, so I know the name of the variable. Can I read this variable of the program or I have to add something to source code?

Comment: No, you cannot do this.

Comment: I'd say there might be a chance, if the C++ application is compiled for debugging.

Comment: You have to add something to the source code, e.g. you could add a TCP API that returns the value. There are many ways for inter-process communication (IPC)

Comment: This one of those "if you have to ask, then the answer is no" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as they wrote, in this form is not possible.
A suggested solution in an earlier post:
[Communication between C++ and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383624/communication-between-c-and-python)